# Vibrating string different density

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Consider small amplitude oscillations of a string fixed between $x=0$ and $x=L$. I know how to analyze this problem both in terms of eigenfunction expansion and travelling wave solutions for a homogeneous string.

But suppose the string is in-homogeneous, so that its density $\rho(x)$ obeys $\rho=\rho_1$ for $0<x<a$ and $\rho = \rho_2$ for $a<x<L$, where $a \in (0,L)$ and, in general, $\rho_1 \neq \rho_2$. We could state the problem as

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{S}{\rho_1}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0, \ 0 < x < a$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} - \frac{S}{\rho_2}\frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial x^2} = 0, \ a < x < L$$
$$u(0,t) = 0, v(L,t) = 0$$
$$u(a,t)=v(a,t)$$
$$u'_x(a,t) = v'_x(a,t)$$

if we assume the tension $S$ to be the same in both strings.

We could also state the problem as

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{S}{\rho}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0, \ 0 < x < L$$
$$u(0,t)=u(L,t)$$
and $\rho=\rho_1$ for $0<x<a$ and $\rho = \rho_2$ for $a<x<L$.

Either way, I'm not sure how to approach this problem. For the second formulation, I thought that one could maybe consider $-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ as a Sturm-Liouville operator on $[0,L]$ with weight function $\rho$, and expand $u$ in the corresponding eigenfunctions. However, since $\rho$ is not continous I'm not sure whether this is allowed.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: @WillieWong If I'm not mistaken, the variable speed case is treated by using $\partial_x(S \partial_xu)$ rather than $S\partial^2_{xx}u$. However, since $S$ is assumed to be constant, this difference is not relevant to my question.

Comment: @WillieWong: The $\rho$ *should* go on the outside in the equation for a vibrating string. It's just Newton's law (force $Su_{xx}$ equals mass $\rho$ times acceleration $u_{tt}$). You might be confusing it with the diffusion equation, which is $u_t = \partial_x ( D(x) u_x)$ if the coefficient $D(x)$ is non-constant.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout: You mean $u_{tt}$ instead of $u_t$, don't you?

Comment: @HansLundmark How silly of me. Thanks! I have edited the question.

Comment: @WillieWong: Well, for a discontinuous $\rho(x)$ one must reinterpret things in terms of distributions, but that's beside the point. For the sake of the discussion, assume that $\rho(x)$ is smooth. Then it goes *outside*, since its proper place is in the "mass times acceleration" term. The restoring force, which tries to straighten out the string, comes from the tension and the curvature of the string, the latter of which is approximated by $-u_{xx}$; it is independent of the density.

Comment: @WillieWong: And also in the Euler–Lagrange formulation, you have a term with $\rho(x) u_t^2$ in the Lagrangian, so when you take $(d/dt) (\partial L/\partial u_t)$, you get something with $\rho(x) u_{tt}$, with $\rho$ on the outside.

Comment: @HansLundmark: ah, you are right, I put the $\rho$ on the wrong side. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @WillieWong: No problem!

Comment: Taking a quick look at Teschl's _Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics_, Chapter 9, he develops Sturm-Liouville with $\rho\in L^1$ so the lack of continuity doesn't seem to be an issue at least to start your analysis. // In your case, the eigenfunctions would look like $\sin( m \sqrt{\rho_1} x)$ between $[0,a]$ and $A \sin( m\sqrt{\rho_2} (x-L))$ between $[a,L]$ with $A, m$ chosen so that the eigenfunctions are $C^1$ (across $a$).

Comment: Travelling waves are more annoying: you have reflections at the end points but partial transmission at $a$. So when you extend the problem by symmetry to be periodic, your travelling wave now have back scattering so the formula would look ugly.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the literature suggestion! Yes, I did arrive at those expressions for the eigenfunctions, but I didn't know if the approach was sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the equation for the eigenfunctions of
$$
                 Lf=\frac{1}{w}\left[-\frac{d}{dx}\left(p\frac{df}{dx}\right)+qf\right]
$$
as $Lf=\lambda f$ and form an equivalent integral equation, you get
$$
                -(pf')'+qf = \lambda w f \\
            -pf'= p(a)f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}(\lambda w-q)f \\
             f(x)=f(a)-\int_{a}^{x}\left(p(a)f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}(\lambda w-q)fdt\right)\frac{1}{p}dx.
$$
So there's really nothing preventing you from getting eigenfunctions once you have the equation in this integral form, provided $p$ does not vanish, even if $p$ has a discontinuity. What will happen is that $pf'$ will be differentiable. So I guess that's the condition you'll want to impose when dealing with the problem piecewise.